# GLM posterior predictive not plotting over complete range of data

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

[I ][1] I can not figure out why the glm posterior predictive is not plotting over the entire data, but only over a fraction of it. And there seem to be no parameters which can alter these. This is the code which generates the following problematic plot.

```
    plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
    x = np.linspace(0,10,30)
    y = x + np.random.normal(2,0.6,len(x))
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    data = dict(x=x, y=y)

    with pm.Model() as model:
        pm.glm.GLM.from_formula('y ~ x', data)
        trace = pm.sample(1000)
    plt.plot(x, y, 'x', label='data')
    pm.plot_posterior_predictive_glm(trace, samples=100,label='posterior predictive 
    regression lines')
    plt.plot(x, trace['Intercept'].mean() + trace['x'].mean()*x, label='true regression 
    line', lw=3., c='y')

    plt.title('Posterior predictive regression lines')
    plt.legend(loc=0)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y');
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NLtP.png

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/plots/posteriorplot.py) `plot_posterior_predictive_glm` default x-axis values are between 0 and 1. You can change that by calling the function as follows:

```
pm.plot_posterior_predictive_glm(trace,samples=100,eval=x,
                                 label='posterior predictive regression lines')
```

Running your code with the above modification I get the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Link to the source is broken, probably moved to Arviz (but I cannot find it in the Arviz repo)